# Storing NSMutableArray to NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

First of all: Merry Christmas everyone! It has been some time since I was able to store data into NSUserDefaults.

In this case I want to store a NSMutableArray to the NSUserDefaults. It is clear to me that you can only store immutable objects to this "file".

I had tried the following code for loading the NSMutableArray:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [defaults objectForKey:@"TestKey"]];
```

I am using the following code for storing the data:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *tempArr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.mutableArray];
[defaults setObject:tempArr forKey:@"TestKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Unfortunately, the simulator exits with the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert non-property list object (
"<MyObject: 0x10dfb40a0>"
) for key TestKey'
```

The mutable array contains NSObjects.

Does anyone have a clue where I am screwing up?

Comment: What is in `self.mutableArray`?

Comment: The self.mutableArray contains NSObjects consisting of NSString elements

Comment: nslog the value of tempArr and check taht does it contains data

Comment: NSLog prints: Temparr is: (
    "<MyObject: 0x10b86c600>"
)

Comment: That does not look like the log of an array.

Comment: It's an array and is correctly logged as an array. The array however consists out of one element, an NSObject. If I add two additional NSObjects to the mutable array the log shows: (
    "<MyObject: 0x112d08a80>",
    "<MyObject: 0x10961b500>",
    "<MyObject: 0x1093d2390>"
)

Comment: Are you sure that your tempArr store just NSString and it's not a custom object?

Comment: temparr is initialised with the content of the mutable array. The mutable array consists of custom objects (NSObjects with name, age, gender all as NSString)

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` can not contain `NSObject`s, see the documentation: A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. You will have to convert your `NSObject` to one of these.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot save tempArr to the NSUserDefaults because as you show in comment this array contains subclasses of MyObject which is custom object. If you want to save it to NSUserDefaults you should implement NSCoding protocol and add two method:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    //Encode all yours properties, vars
    [encoder encodeObject:self.property1 forKey:@"property1"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.property2 forKey:@"property2"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        //decode all yours properties, vars
        self.property1 = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"property1"];
        self.property2 = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"property2"];
    }
    return self;
```

But NSUserDefaults was design to store just simple data and if you want to save more custom objects you should consider save it to the file, have a look on NSKeyedArchiver maybe that will be more suitable for you. Just remember that if you want to save custom object with NSKeyedArchiver the object should conform to NSCoding protocol as well and you have to add this two method above too.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

To Archive:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:YOUR_MUTABLE_ARRAY];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"myarray"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To Unarchive:

```
NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myarray"];
NSMutableArray *mArr = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: Missing that the custom object will have to support the `NSCoding` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` can not handle custom objects.

From the Apple docs:

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.

For custom objects either convert then to one of these objects or implement the `NSCoder` protocol for the class to create an `NSData` representation.

For more than a small number of parameters the best choice is either `CoreData` or `NSKeyedArchiver` saving to a file in the Documents directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your two options are:

1. Implement NSCoding in `MyObject` and then use a NSKeyedArchiver
2. Use CoreData

A very good tutorial and a comparison of both can be found here: http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

Comment: Concise answer with a great link. Unfortunately it does not answer the question nor why, the comments and/or other answers are necessary to provide the necessary context. Consider adding why the OP's `NSUserDefaults` won't work.